# UPDATE with SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I need to UPDATE 2 lines on a table using SQLite but I don't get it. 
I tried this:

```
UPDATE table
SET column1=value1, column2=value2
WHERE table.id=1
SET column1=value3,column2=value4
WHERE table.id=2
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run two separate queries:

```
UPDATE table
SET column1=value1, column2=value2
WHERE table.id=1;

UPDATE table
SET column1=value3,column2=value4
WHERE table.id=2;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did it with two separate queries and my table was updated.